# How can $\Omega$ can be uncountable, but $G=\{\{w\}: w\in\Omega \}$ can be countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I don't understand how $\Omega$ can be uncountable, but $G=\{\{w\}: w\in \Omega \}$ can be countable. What would be the natural number associated with $\{2\}\in G$?

Why would taking the singletons change anything?

Suppose $G$ is countable.

Let us take the set of non singletons: $H=\{k: k\in \Omega \} $. I could create a one to one mapping between $H$ and $G$ by saying $\{w_i\}\to k_i$ . But $H$ is just $\Omega$ which we said was uncountable, so it's a contradiction. Hence $G$ must be uncountable.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is uncountable then so is $G:=\{\{w\}\mid w\in\Omega\}$. The map $w\mapsto\{w\}$ is a bijection $\Omega\to G$.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, $\Omega$ and $\{\{w\}: w\in\Omega\}$ always have the same cardinality - the map $w\mapsto \{w\}$ is a bijection.

Maybe you misread the claim (where *did* you see this claimed?); it is true that $\{w: \{w\}\in\Omega\}$ can be countable, even if $\Omega$ isn't (e.g. if $\Omega$ consists entirely of *two*-element sets).